# Parallel REST API calls through Azure ADB2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

In my use case, I have a single AD B2C tenant to handle a user authentication requests coming from a single web-application. However, in the existing login flow, once user enter a login email and passcode, next orchestrion is to make a backend REST api call to check the user existence, and that is working as expected.

To enhance this login flow in b2c, and to handle an authentication requests coming from a ‘Two different web applications’, we need to make a parallel REST api calls based on the request url.

I assume, as a first step In B2C need to look for a ‘query parameter’ in the request url, to handle this multiple rest api calls based on a query parameter from the website request url. I’m not sure if b2c can support a parallel REST api calls from a single custom policy.

But how to handle these multiple authentication requests are coming from two a two different web applications to b2c through b2c custom policy? Any helpful documentation or examples to support this usecase would be greatly helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "parallel"?

If you have two applications, they have different clientIDs and different redirectURI. I assume you mean they both use the same user flow?

The user flow calls an API.

In B2C, each auth request runs in a separate "sandbox", so if each application sends an auth request at the same time, each auth request is running in parallel.

The user flows are running in parallel, not the API.

A user flow can only call one API at a time, and that has to be completed before it can call another API.

Use this:

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="Flag1" DefaultValue="{OAUTH-KV:Flag1}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
```

where Flag1 is the value in the query string and similarly for Flag2.

Then do:

```
<OrchestrationStep Order="x" Type="ClaimsExchange">
    <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
            <Value>Flag1</Value>
            <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
    </Preconditions>
    <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="Call-API-1" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="REST API Flag1"/>
    </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>

<OrchestrationStep Order="x+1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
    <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
            <Value>Flag2</Value>
            <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
    </Preconditions>
    <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="Call-API-2" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="REST API Flag2"/>
    </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

Comment: Thanks @rbrayb. So, it’s a simultaneous calls to the backend rest api. Based on the authentication requests from the websites to a single b2c tenant, we need to identify that request endpoint based on a query parameter in the request header. And according make a subsequent rest api calls in B2C. Working on the above-mentioned approach. If possible, pls share a reference links.

Comment: No, they are not simultaneous. They are serial. API-1 is called first and then when that completes, API-2 is called. In terms of query parameters, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview